# Audio cuts out when CPU usage rises above ~30%

Tags: windows-7, audio

I've just built a new PC:

- Intel Core i3 2100 CPU
- 4GB 1333MHz DDR3 memory
- Intel H67 Chipset motherboard
- Using the onboard graphics
- Using the onboard sound - Realtek* ALC662 audio codec

When playing audio only it appears to be OK, but when playing videos and games the sound will repeatedly cut out for approximately a second 2 or 3 times and then start again. When it does cut out we get a notification that the speakers have been unplugged (although clearly they haven't).

One piece of information we found indicates that it's [related to CPU usage](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-7/892192-realtek-hd-audio-cuts-out.html) and this does seem to be the case. It would also explain why it's more of a problem when video is involved as the CPU is doing everything.

We've checked that we've got the latest drivers installed and if anything the problem seems to be getting worse.

Is the only solution going to be getting a dedicated graphics card?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/64847/realtek-hd-spdif-cuts-in-and-out-on-windows-7) doesn't answer the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We uninstalled the Realtek software that came with the motherboard (it was installed as a side effect of installing the audio drivers) and now everything seems to be OK.

We assume that it's because the audio isn't being processed by extra software (though if someone can explain this better feel free).

Comment: The drivers or software could have been bad, you could try a more recent version from online if you need the software. Glad that you had it solved... :)

Comment: @Tom - we couldn't find any newer drivers (though I haven't double checked the results).