# Win 7 audio cuts out or doesn't work at all. Realtek is already uninstalled.

Tags: windows-7, audio

I had [this](https://superuser.com/questions/298905/audio-cuts-out-when-cpu-usage-rises-above-30) problem - audio kept cutting out every time CPU usage was high, and the computer kept acting like I was unplugging my speakers. As recommended in that thread, I uninstalled the Realtek software that had come with the mobo drivers, and that fixed it for a while. But now the problem is back - the audio cuts out frequently, or doesn't work at all. As far as I can tell, the problems started after I installed Java, although that might be a coincidence.

I've updated the Windows sound drivers, but that didn't fix it. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a different version of the Realtek High Definition Audio Driver than I'd had before ended up fixing the problem.